# Есть ли еще такие слова?

Tags: омонимы, ономастика

От названий городов *Гусь-Хрустальный, Каменск-Уральский* и *Петропавловск-Камчатский* [образуется по два прилагательных](http://khvorostin.com/language/kamensk-uralsky/):

- гусевский / Гусь-Хрустальный,
- каменский / Каменск-Уральский,
- петропавловский / Петропавловск-Камчатский

Есть ли ещё существительные в русском языке, являющиеся омографами прилагательных, образованных от них?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никогда не слышал, чтобы от Петропавловска-Камчатского прилагательным было бы просто "камчатский". Оно может образовываться только от первого слова, как основного, вторая часть всегда - уточняющая. 
Далее, само название "омограф" в данном случае неоправдано.

А вообще, если смотреть на вопрос, а не на примеры, то все многочисленные топонимы советской эпохи типа "Первомайский", "Октябрьский" или "Ленинский" порождали прилагательные, неотличимые от самого топонима.

Comment: Ага. Неотфильтровал. Конечно же, "петропавловский".

Почему "омограф" неоправдано?

За наводку на советские топонимы - спасибо. Только тут скорее существительные от прилагательных образованы.

Comment: Во-первых, потому, что ваши названия не являются омографичными. Омографы - это слова, совпадающие с точностью до буквы. А какмнсе и Каменский таковыми не являются.
Во-вторых, когда омографы являются и омонимами логично их назвать именно омонимами.

Comment: Каменск-Уральский, Гусь-Хрустальный, Петропавловск-Камчатский - точность до буквы. Речь о них.

Имея желание указать именно на "точность до буквы", использую именно слово "омографы". Даже если это и омофоны.

Comment: Подождите, вы же пишете, что прилагательное - одно слово?
Никогда полные названия не использовались в качестве прилагательных.
Уж точно. В названиях каких-то горсоветов - еще допускаю, хотя тоже сомневаюсь.

Comment: А разве от Гусь-Хрустальный прилагательное не Гусь-Хрустальненский (завод, например)

Comment: Да по-разному можно. Исторически - гусевской.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы тоже не называла эти прилагательные омонимами. Потому что омонимы - это слова **одной и той же части речи**  с  **разным** лексическим значением, но одинаково оформленные графически. Подобных пар много. Это все существительные, образованные от прилагательных неморфемным способом: будущее, прошлое, столовая, учительская и т.д.

Comment: Хм. Можно ссылку на такое определение? В Википедии читаю: "[Совпадающие слова, относящиеся к разным частям речи, все или почти все российские лингвисты безусловно относят к омонимам. Примером таких омонимов являются «течь» (протекать) и «течь» (протекание).](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%EC%EE%ED%E8%EC)" + [статья "Омонимы" в БСЭ](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B/%D0%91%D0%A1%D0%AD/%D0%9E%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B/)

Comment: Читайте Википедию - свободную от всякой ответственности энциклопедию!  
Я так понимаю, что у Ларf, как и везде в этой теме, речь идет от **омографах**.